# Display Message callback not invoking - Firebase in-app messaging

Tags: android, firebase, android-custom-view, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying to customise the firebase in-app messages.

I am following this article :https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/customize-messages

As per the article I have created my own implementation of **FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay**  class.

```
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay;
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplayCallbacks;
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.model.InAppMessage;

public class MyMessageDisplayImplementation implements 
FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay {
    @Override
    public void displayMessage(InAppMessage inAppMessage
        , FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplayCallbacks 
    firebaseInAppMessagingDisplayCallbacks) {
         Log.e("INAPP_MESSAGE","received an inapp message");
    }
}
```

Then registered this implementation with the headless Firebase In-App Messaging SDK

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessageDisplayComponent(new MyMessageDisplayImplementation());
}
```

}

My problem is that, I am not getting the displyaMessage() callback.

When I commented out the line of code, `" FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessageDisplayComponent(new MyMessageDisplayImplementation());"` from Application class, it is showing the default message. But, nothing is happening when I put this code back.

Please help if anyone knows better idea about this in-app message customisation.

Comment: hey, bro, have you found any solution, please post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information on the firebase doc is little bit confusing.  Actually its very simple.

Added these dependencies in app level gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:17.0.3")
```

Note: We don't need to add "***implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.1.1***'" dependency

Register the DisplayMessage component on starting activity.

```
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessaging
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay

///////

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.e("MESSAGE", "activity started")
    var firebaseInAppMessagingDisplay = FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay { inAppMessage, cb ->
        // You can show the message here.
        // The variable inAppMessage has all information about the campaign that we putting in console (title, content, image url.. etc)
        Log.e("MESSAGE", "Display Message callback invoked")
    }
    FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessageDisplayComponent(firebaseInAppMessagingDisplay)
}
```

Comment: Can you help me?  When I implement the callback is never called

Answer (score 2):

[This GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/164) fixed the problem for me.

In short, the problem is caused by the Firebase SDK setting its own listener when your activity resumes, overwriting the listener you set with `setMessageDisplayComponent`.

To fix the issue I moved my own listener code from `onStart` to `onResume`, ensuring my listener would be the last one added and become the one that receives the messages.